# Magento 2 - Default Refund Shipping charge to be 0 on Credit Memo

Tags: magento2, shipping, creditmemo, refund

I don't want to refund the shipping charge on issuing a refund.

How to i set it to 0 by default.

Comment: WOW still no answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can move the following file to your own theme: view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/totals/adjustments.phtml

```
<td>
    <input type="text"
           name="creditmemo[shipping_amount]"
           value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getShippingAmount() ?>"
           class="input-text admin__control-text not-negative-amount"
           id="shipping_amount" />
</td>
```

Update `value` to be "0" instead of `"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getShippingAmount() ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a Partial Refund for your order.

Beside on refund, you are able to shift the amount of Refund Shipping

[image]